# Xcode5 In my simple flappy bird clone, how would I generate tunnels faster?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, flappy-bird-clone

My flappy bird clone doesn't use Spritebuilder. It is just a simple app, which I find almost exactly the same. I can regenerate tunnels every time they reach the end of the screen but that just makes the game slow because the bird has to wait the entire screen for another tunnel. How could I generate tunnels as quick (or close to) as the real flappy bird?

Comment: Maybe if you posted the section of your code where you are coding the generation of the pipes would it be easier to figure out how to help you.

Comment: Sorry for that. I started all of this yesterday so I'm a huge rookie. I have it in game.m -(void)PipeMoving            If(PipeTop.center.x < -22) [self PlacePipes];  sorry typing this from ipad

Comment: @DJHead-On I'm on my computer now if you need to know the full code for PickMoving. I tried switching -22 to say 40 but then the pipe just regenerates half way through the screen which isn't right

Comment: Someone please help me out!

Comment: @MrHaze Sorry man I can't seem to get any help on this. Any ideas?

Comment: Please guys just looking for a little help